# wpseo_register_var_replacement() adding more variables

Tags: wordpress, variables, replace, yoast

I want to add more values (variables) to yoast seo plugin at once. I tried to return it with an array for the get variable function but its not working. For only one variable its working fine!

Here is the code thats works, with just one variable:

```
/ define the custom replacement callback
function get_myname() {
    return 'My name is Moses';
}

// define the action for register yoast_variable replacments
function leweb_yoast_variables_2() {
    wpseo_register_var_replacement( '%%myname%%', 'get_myname', 'advanced', 'some help text' );
}

// Add action
add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'leweb_yoast_variables_2');
```

So this code above is working fine! But i want to create more replacements at one time and, so i tried this code:

```
/ define the custom replacement callback
function get_myname() {
    // return 'My name is Moses';
    return array ('foo', 'bar');
}

// define the action for register yoast_variable replacments
function leweb_yoast_variables_2() {
    wpseo_register_var_replacement( '%%myname%%', 'get_myname[0]', 'advanced', 'some help text' );
}

// Add action
add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'leweb_yoast_variables_2');
```

But its not working and the function wpseo_register_var_replacement() requires a function at the second parameter.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't parse the second argument passed to `wpseo_register_var_replacement` as PHP code. So, it'll try to find a function named `get_myname[0]`, which doesn't exist -- actually can't exist.

You probably have more options to do what you want, but I can think of two now:

1. Create one function for each of your replacements.
2. Use an anonymous function.

**Example for solution for #1**

```
function get_var1() {
    return 'foo';
}

function get_var2() {
    return 'bar';
}

function register_yoast_vars() {
    wpseo_register_var_replacement('%%var_1%%', 'get_var1', 'advanced', 'some help text');
    wpseo_register_var_replacement('%%var_2%%', 'get_var2', 'advanced', 'some help text');
}

add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_yoast_vars');
```

**Example solution for #2**

```
function register_yoast_vars() {
    wpseo_register_var_replacement('%%var_1%%', function () { return 'foo'; }, 'advanced', 'some help text');
    wpseo_register_var_replacement('%%var_2%%', function () { return 'bar'; }, 'advanced', 'some help text');
}

add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_yoast_vars');
```